# Memory leak and Memory_free_on_stack variable in c++ while running in checkmarx

Tags: c++, security, checkmarx

I am trying to remediate the vulnerabilities that is deducted by checkmarx tool. Below is the sample code which is similar to my project that I am currently working on which is throwing memory leak and memory free on stack variables.

Memory is allocated in the called function and deleted in Main function.

If sum is allocated in the main function, there won't be any Memory leak or Memory free on stack variables.  But I couldn't do the same in my actual code which involves some other variables to determine the size of the pointer variables before allocating.

```
void addition(int *a, int *b, int** sum)
{
    *sum = new int[2]; //MEMORY LEAK is thrown here

    if (*sum)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            cout << "Enter two numbers: " <<endl;
            cin >> a[i] >> b[i];
            (*sum)[i] = a[i] + b[i];
            cout << "sum:" << (*sum)[i] << endl;

        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int* p1 = NULL;
    p1=new int[2];
    int* p2 = NULL;
    p2 =new int[2];
    int *sum = NULL; //MemoryFree_On_StackVariable is thrown here

    addition(p1 ,p2, &sum);  

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cout << "sum is " << sum[i] << endl;
    }
    if (p1)
    {
        delete[] p1;
        p1 = NULL;
        cout << "p1 is deleted" <<endl;
    }
    if (p2)
    {
        delete[] p2;
        p2 = NULL;
        cout << "p2 is deleted" <<endl;
    }

    if (sum != NULL)
    {
        delete[] sum;
        sum = NULL;

        cout << " sum is deleted" << endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

How could I rectify the vulnerability? are those vulnerability thrown rightly?
should the memory be allocated and deleted in same function?

Comment: Why don't you just use stl containers? Or at least wrap the sum type into a simple class, that frees the memory on destruction.
Using raw `new` and `delete` is just bad style and will at some point leak memory.

Comment: I don't know what this tool you are using is about, but I can't see any leaks in the code above. It's perfectly OK to allocate memory in one function and free it in another.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I don't know why in your case you have a memory leak because **everything seems correct** (to me at least).

But if you call `addition()` several times with the same `sum` pointer, you will create memory leaks for sure (except if you don't forget to `delete[] sum;` before each additional call to `addition()`) because you open the door to reallocate an already allocated memory which causes a memory leak.

I think this could be a reason to allocate/deallocate memory in the same scope. But in your case, I really don't understand.
I already had done similar things (delegate the deallocation task elsewhere) and I had no problems with it.

---

**EDIT:**

I don't know the checkmarx tool you are using. But it seems that it is not able to keep tracking pointers through function calls.
This is why it says that you try to free a stack variable in the `main()` function and why it says you don't delete an allocated variable in the `addition()` function.
This explains why it is expecting allocation/deallocation in the same block.

According to me, you don't have any error, but checkmarx is not working as it should do. Perhaps you can use Valgrind for your check instead.